# Insert more document.querySelector

Tags: jquery

I am using this feature, allowing me to move a div within a block:

```js
function moveDiv(){
var dragItem = document.querySelector("#myWebcamDraggable");
var container = document.querySelector(".blocco-chat-contenitore");
var contar = document.querySelector(".movediv");


    var active = false;
    var currentX;
    var currentY;
    var initialX;
    var initialY;
    var xOffset = 0;
    var yOffset = 0;

    container.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);

    container.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
    container.addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
    container.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);

    function dragStart(e) {
      if (e.type === "touchstart") {
        initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
        initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
      } else {
        initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
        initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
      }


      if (e.target === contar) {
        active = true;
      }
    }

    function dragEnd(e) {
      initialX = currentX;
      initialY = currentY;

      active = false;
    }

    function drag(e) {
      if (active) {
      
        e.preventDefault();
      
        if (e.type === "touchmove") {
          currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
          currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
        } else {
          currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
          currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
        }

        xOffset = currentX;
        yOffset = currentY;

        setTranslate(currentX, currentY, dragItem);
      }
    }

    function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
      el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
    }

};
```

```html
<div class="popup-cam-block" id="myWebcamDraggable" ><div class="jsPanel-titlebar"><div class="movediv"></div></div>
```

how can i use this function, using other div and other class or id?
I tried with

```html
var dragItem = document.querySelectorALL("#myWebcamDraggable.test");
var container = document.querySelector(".blocco-chat-contenitore");
var contar = document.querySelectorAll(".movediv.testaddclass");
```

but it doesn't work ... can I use the same function for more classes? thanks
I hope I made myself understood, I would like to add class or div so that we can use the function yes more blocks div

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your desired result is, however `document.querySelectorALL` is invalid due to the invalid case of `All`.  And an id selector will only ever return just one element so using the All version is not really necessary

Answer (score 0):

try giving the id or class (css selector) as a function parameter.
so your method signature would be:

```
 function moveDiv(sccSelector){
     var dragItem = document.querySelector(sccSelector);
     ...
```